# using getJSON in a class (scoping issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

```
//this is a class
function SpriteSheetClass()
{
    this.sprite="local";

    $.getJSON(url, this.onLoaded);      
}   

SpriteSheetClass.prototype.onLoaded= function(json) 
{
    console.log(this.sprite); //returns undefined!

    //I am out of SpriteSheetClass scope! how do I store the json???
}

var a=new SpriteSheetClass()
```

When the getJSON callback is executed, the scope is not in the class. 
There is no way to bind the returned json with my class instance (a)

Keep in mind I want to keep the calls async, and I need to create many instances of SpriteSheetClass
This is not a timing question, it is a scope question.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the callback function is called, `this` will not be the object, but the `$.getJSON` function.

You can bind the value of `this` to the callback, so it will be the object instead

```
$.getJSON(url, this.onLoaded.bind(this));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUPC8/)

Answer (score 1):

With modern day browsers you can use [function.bind(thisArg)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to keep the proper scope.

```
function SpriteSheetClass() {
    this.sprite="local";
    $.getJSON(url, this.onLoaded.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A local wrapper function will do the job:

```
function SpriteSheetClass() 
{
   this.sprite="local";
   var that = this;

   var callback = function(data) {
     that.onLoaded(data);
   };

   $.getJSON(url, callback);
}
```